# fast crossproduct for recursive matrices

Tags: r, recursion, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a recursive computation for a matrix A (this will be a hat-matrix), for example:

`A(i) = A(i-1) + crossprod(B,A(i-1))`

For each step `i` I need the trace of `A(i)`.  Is there a faster way to implement this in R than the following implementation:

```
# define random matrices
set.seed(123)
n <- 7^2*10^4
steps <- 10
A <- matrix(rnorm(n), ncol=sqrt(n))
B <- matrix(rnorm(n), ncol=sqrt(n))

# preallocation
Amat <- traceA <- vector("list", steps)
Amat[[1]] <- A

# recursive computation for matrix A(i)
ptm <- proc.time()
for(i in 2:steps){
  Amat[[i]] <- Amat[[i-1]] + crossprod(B,Amat[[i-1]])
  traceA[[i]] <- sum(diag(Amat[[i]]))
}
proc.time() - ptm
```

I would like to mention that the matrix A(i) and the matrix B are symmetric and idempotent (because they are hat matrices of a linear model) and can be extremely big. I guess that parallel computation will fail here, because the for-loop needs the matrix A(i-1) of the step before.

The idea behind this is a likelihood-based boosting algorithm, where I need the trace of each boosting iteration of the hat-matrix that could be computed as mentioned above.

Comment: Search about the ATLAS Rblas library as switching from the default library can significantly improve the performance of your matrix multiplications.

Comment: Do you care about `Amat`? If you only need to store the trace, you could take advantage of two important results regarding the trace (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)). The first one is `trace(A+B) = trace(A) + trace(B)`. The second one is `trace(X'Y) = sum(as.vector(X) * as.vector(Y))`.

Comment: @flodel, is there a reason to cast `as.vector` here, since `*` is the hadamard product for matrices?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft: you are right, `as.vector` is not needed.

Comment: @frodel I just using the trick `trace(A[i]) = trace(A[i-1]) + sum(B*A[i-1])` will just work for the first iteration... I think the problem with you suggestion is that I need the full matrix `A[i-1]` to compute the trace of `A[i]`. For this, I have to use the crossproduct in each step and store the full matrices `A[i]` for all steps `i`. I have to combine your suggestion with eddi's answer. I'll try, it should/could work, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `Amat_i`'s can be written as `Amat_i = (1+t(B))^(i-1) * A` and since you mention that `B*B = B` or `t(B)*t(B) = t(B)`, then

```
 (1+B)^n = 1 + choose(n,1)*B + choose(n,2)*B^2 + ...
         = 1 + B * (choose(n,1) + choose(n,2) + ... + choose(n,n))
         = 1 + B * (2^n - 1)
```

Putting it all together then:

```
 tr(Amat_i) = tr(A) + (2^(i-1) - 1) * tr(t(B)*A)
```

So just calculate the two traces and then you won't need to do any more matrix multiplications to get all of the `tr(Amat_i)`'s.

Comment: Nice answer. Just to make it clear, readers should note that your `1` is actually the identity matrix. Also, you denote the matrix product by `*` in the first and last formulas. Last, but not least, I'd note that @flodel's tip (`tr(t(B)%*%A)==sum(B*A)`) is much faster for large matrices.

Comment: Thank you. This helped, what if the matrix `B` changes (not recursively) in each step, such that in the first step we have `B1`, in the second step `B2`, and so on?

Comment: @Giuseppe then the above formula will not apply (and that's really all I can say with the information you've provided).